# How do online stroke order dictionaries render intermediate stages?

Tags: characters, software, stroke-order

How does software like https://www.an2.net/zi/ and other stroke order dictionaries and practice tools (including authoritative sources like [Taiwan's MoE](https://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/characters.do?lang=zh_TW)) know how to generate the iterative images of correct strokes?

[image]

I would like to make some software that does the same but with my own preferred more customisable visual output. How can I get these kinds of images/fonts/data (whatever they are using) into my own program?

Answer (score 4):

The data on how to draw characters (including stroke order) is freely available via [Make Me a Hanzi](https://github.com/skishore/makemeahanzi#make-me-a-hanzi-demo).  The file `graphics.txt` contains vector graphics files for each character, stroke by stroke.

For example, the entry for 休 is

```
{"character":"休","strokes":["M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z","M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z","M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z","M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z","M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z","M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z"],"medians":[[[291,766],[316,742],[327,716],[296,650],[194,482],[99,364],[59,327]],[[242,510],[250,473],[260,456],[260,369],[252,215],[237,110],[242,24]],[[379,515],[401,508],[450,506],[603,530],[775,568],[823,567]],[[541,816],[587,773],[595,751],[589,224],[578,47],[580,-28]],[[564,496],[556,488],[542,420],[467,299],[385,200],[307,140]],[[617,475],[630,444],[681,371],[744,287],[803,223],[853,203],[964,174]]]}
```

which you can edit in your favorite software in all sorts of ways.  For example, I'm familiar with tikz in LaTeX, so I used the Make Me a Hanzi data to draw:

> [image: a drawing of 休 I made using tikz]

This is the LaTeX code I used to draw the above:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.08]
\draw[fill=red!10!yellow,ultra thick] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\draw[fill=red!25!yellow,thin] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
\draw[fill=red!40!yellow,dotted] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
\draw[fill=red!55!yellow,densely dotted] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
\draw[fill=red!70!yellow,thick] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
\draw[fill=red!85!yellow,very thick] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}
 
\end{document}
```

To turn this into a stroke-order graphic, we add surrounding boxes, and repeatedly draw the characters, deleting the relevant strokes:

> [image: How to draw 休, stroke by stroke]

My LaTeX code for this is:

```
\documentclass[crop,margin=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
% \fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.1]
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, -124";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 -124 L 1024 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 512 -124 L 512 900";
\draw[thick, dotted, black!40] svg  "M 0 388 L 1024 388";
\draw[ultra thick] svg  "M 0, 900 L 1024, 900 L 1024, -124 L 0 -124 Z";

\fill[black!50] svg "M 246 517 Q 280 566 318 628 Q 343 677 368 701 Q 378 713 372 727 Q 368 740 338 763 Q 310 782 289 782 Q 270 779 279 756 Q 294 725 282 697 Q 222 543 63 344 Q 53 334 50 327 Q 46 315 61 318 Q 100 328 218 479 L 246 517 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 218 479 Q 236 443 236 367 Q 235 351 235 331 Q 234 222 202 111 Q 192 66 226 15 Q 227 15 229 12 Q 247 -4 259 23 Q 274 63 273 110 Q 279 377 289 436 Q 296 463 287 474 Q 248 516 246 517 C 225 538 207 507 218 479 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 613 510 Q 680 523 754 534 Q 820 547 829 555 Q 839 562 835 572 Q 828 585 798 593 Q 768 600 737 590 Q 676 571 613 556 L 570 546 Q 485 531 387 525 Q 350 521 376 502 Q 419 475 475 487 Q 509 493 546 499 L 613 510 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 612 495 Q 612 502 613 510 L 613 556 Q 613 680 631 748 Q 646 773 620 792 Q 604 804 574 821 Q 550 837 529 822 Q 525 816 531 801 Q 565 752 566 701 Q 567 628 570 546 L 568 418 Q 565 193 556 140 Q 534 40 551 -4 Q 554 -11 559 -22 Q 566 -40 574 -43 Q 581 -50 588 -42 Q 615 -18 614 41 Q 613 87 612 442 L 612 495 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 546 499 Q 495 334 305 147 Q 295 134 304 133 Q 325 127 405 194 Q 474 255 568 418 C 628 521 556 530 546 499 Z";
\fill[black!50] svg "M 612 442 Q 679 324 768 197 Q 786 175 817 172 Q 926 165 960 167 Q 970 168 972 173 Q 973 179 959 187 Q 826 250 778 298 Q 703 376 612 495 C 594 519 597 468 612 442 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To draw this, we need to know [the coordinates](https://www.skishore.me/makemeahanzi/):

> Each stroke is laid out on a 1024x1024 size coordinate system where:
>
> - The upper-left corner is at position (0, 900).
> - The lower-right corner is at position (1024, -124).

Comment: What a great resource! But it doesn't have graphics entries for characters like 㠭, 麤 which I've seen other sites render no problem